# Split modificando a ordenação do arquivo de texto

Tags: c#, asp.net

Estou carregando um arquivo de texto em um string [], posteriormente fazendo um split pois o arquivo é separado por espaços, porém notei que linhas estão com tamanhos diferentes, isso está atrapalhando a captura de posições em cada uma das linhas do arquivo, no código de exemplo, só consigo capturar o texto da posição 65, quando na verdade a posição correta era 231 até 239, o arquivo no notepad está correto, porém, dentro do código não.

```
public static string CarregaTxt()
{
string[] array = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\aoliveira\source\repos\BRR23120.ret");

string resultado = "";
for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{                  
resultado = array[i];
string[] returnDataSplited = resultado.Split(' ');
string code = returnDataSplited[65];
var data = GetReturnMessage(code);
Console.WriteLine(resultado);

}
return resultado.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Adicione ao menos a linha de dados de exemplo onde vc encontra o erro e outra onde está correto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ao usar o código abaixo você não pegará uma substring da sua string original (`resultado`).

```cs
resultado = array[i];
string[] returnDataSplited = resultado.Split(' ');
string code = returnDataSplited[65];
```

Se o que vc pretende é pegar o texto da posição 231 à 239 vc deverá usar o método [substring](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_Substring_System_Int32_System_Int32_). O primeiro atributo é a posição inicial (231, no seu caso - mas note que a contagem inicia pelo zero) e o segundo é o tamanho do texto que vc pretende obter (8, por exemplo).

```cs
resultado = array[i];
string code = resultado.Substring(231, 8);
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado tvdias, infelizmente só tinha obtido respostas negativas, mas sua resposta foi simples e direta, resolveu o problema. Eu também havia tido uma outra ideia para sanar esse problema, porém com substring ficou bem melhor.